# Как получить содержимое div title с помощью BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
<td class="court">
<div class="b-container">
<div class="judge" title="Щавлева А. Л.">Щавлева А. Л.</div>
<div title="АС Владимирской области">АС Владимирской области</div>
</div>
</td>
```

Подскажите, как получить значение div title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить значение `title` атрибута первого `<div>` элемента, имеющего данный атрибут:

```
title = soup.find('div', title=True)["title"]
```

> если в этом же soup есть еще несколько элементов div с атрибутом title, то как получить значение 2-го, 3-го, и так далее?

Можно получить список `<div>` элементов, используя [`find_all()` метод](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
titles = [div['title'] for div in soup.find_all('div', title=True)]
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если в этом же soup есть еще несколько элементов div с атрибутом title, то как получить значение 2-го, 3-го, и так далее?

Comment: Спасибо! Наконец-то понял логику, можно вытащить из полученного списка любой нужный элемент, в данном случае - нужный title